# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types: Are native libries for SQL Server preinstalled on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I just upgraded my app to use the latest Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package v14 from v13. This resulted in an well-documented runtime error. The reason here would be missing native libraries:

```
Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found
```

The Nuget package also contains the native DLLs that were missing, so I could theoretically copy them to my bin folder and load them through my code, but:

- I didn't have to do that with my v13 binaries
- When I deployed the updated project to Azure, it ran just fine.

My current assumption would be that I got the v13 binaries with my local SQL install, and on Azure, those binaries (both v13 / v14) are preinstalled.

However, when googling a bit about the issue, most developers have the opposite problem of things not working on Azure due to the missing libs, so I wonder whether not going the manual route might be dangerous with regards to Azure deployments. If anybody had some insight here, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the azure web service install the SQL server SDK version is 9.0 - 13.0. So you need install 14.0 by yourself.

You could find the dll in the kudu console in your web service.

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies>
```

To open the kudu you could refer to below steps:

1.Find the Advanced Tools in DEVELOPMENT TOOLS click go.

[image]

2.Click dubug console's cmd.

[image]

3.Find the path.
Notice: You need firstly type cd.. to locate the root path.

You could find the Microsoft.SqlServer file as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Brando. However, I'm seeing the same thing, but as mentioned, the upgrade to v14 worked on Azure but not locally even though I didn't have a "140" folder. However, good to know this is all there by default - thanks!